# Trouble creating sql server INSTEAD OF INSERT Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm having problems with creating an instead of insert trigger and I was hoping someone could point me what I'm doing wrong.
I have a table with employees id and functionalities id and the functionalities with id 2 or 4 are only available to the employees with id 1 or 4, any other combination is ok.
I created this trigger but no matter what I insert, the result is always a null value in each column.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrigInsertEmployee
ON employee_func
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @idEmp int, @idFunc int

IF(@idFunc IN (2, 4) AND @idEmp NOT IN (1, 4))
BEGIN
REISERROR('Incorrect functionality', 10, 1)
RETURN
END

INSERT INTO employee_func(idEmp, idFunc) VALUES (@idEmp ,@idFunc)
END
```

Hope someone can help me out!
Thanks

Comment: You declared the variables `@idEmp` and `@idFunc` but you never give them a value, so of course you are inserting `NULL`s

Answer (score 0):

You declared two variables but never set them.  When writing an INSERT trigger, SQL exposes a special table called *inserted* that holds the values the calling process is attempting to insert.  See the link below for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As dazedandconfused mentioned, the `INSERTED` "special" table is what you need. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrigInsertEmployee
ON employee_func
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS

BEGIN

  IF(INSERTED.idFunc IN (2, 4) AND INSERTED.idEmp NOT IN (1, 4))
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Incorrect functionality', 10, 1)
    RETURN
  END

  INSERT INTO employee_func(idEmp, idFunc) VALUES (@idEmp ,@idFunc)
END
```

Also, it may just be a transposition error, but `RAISERROR` wasn't spelled right in your code.

Finally, for a simple row-based rule like this you could use a `CHECK` constraint instead:

```
ALTER TABLE employee_func
ADD CHECK ( NOT(idFunc IN (2, 4) AND idEmp NOT IN (1, 4)) )
```

I'm just wrapping a "NOT" around your trigger condition here, as the CHECK defines something that's OK whereas your trigger defines something that *isn't* OK.